# Can't access private class members inside of static method?

Tags: c++, windows, class, methods, static

I have the following setup:

```
//.h
class Cell
{
private:
    POINT   mCellStartingPoint;
    int     mXoffset;
    int     mYoffset;
public:
    static void DrawRowOfPixels(int yoff);
    Cell();
    ~Cell();
};

//.cpp
void Cell::DrawRowOfPixels(int yoff)
{
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    COLORREF red = 0xFF0000;
    for(int i = mCellStartingPoint.x; i < mXoffset; i++)
    {
        SetPixel(dc, mCellStartingPoint.x + i, mCellStartingPoint + yoff, red);
    }
}
```

However, when implementing the DrawRowOfPixels() method in the .cpp file, I get errors at all of the member variables of the Cell class. (i.e. mCellStartingpoint, mXoffset, and mYoffset)

> error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union
>
> error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Cell::mXoffset'
>
> error C3867: 'Cell::mXoffset': function call missing argument list; use '&Cell::mXoffset' to create a pointer to member
>
> error: A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

I know I'm probably doing something really stupid, but what's going on here? Why can't I use my private member variables inside my static member function like I should be able to?

Comment: There's a logical reason static member functions can't access non-static data members. It's part of the definition of a static member function.

Comment: It would likely help immensely if you had an **object** to go with those data members. You're using a static class function. It has no object, therefore no members. Make the function non-static, pass an object in as a parameter, or make the members static. any of the above will work. Choose the right one to fit your need.

Comment: So I literally can't access them then?  I thought the point of a static function was to be able to be called without an object but still have the same use as if it were called by an object.

Comment: @user2057387, If it has no object, which object's set of data members does it use?

Comment: Why do these things only make sense after I make an idiot of myself on the internet...

Comment: @EdS. it was an honest mistake, my comment was meant for the OP

Comment: you can't achieve what you are trying to achieve without making your data members static. Better understanding of basics would help you a lot, read and learn:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot access a non static member inside a `static` method unless you explicitly make available the object instance inside the member function.(*Pass object instance explicitly as argument or use a global instance which can be accessed inside the function*)

For a non static member function an implicit `this` pointer is passed as the first argument to the function. The `this` pointer is dereferenced inside the member function to access the members. `static` members are not passed with the implicit `this` pointer so you cannot access non static members inside the function unless you explicitly get the object inside the member function.