# gdb not showing ''this'' when stepping in a static method of a singleton?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, debug-symbols

I have the following situation. This is the stripped down version of the class. I'm running it in Qt creator and using Qt in the real scenario.

```
class MyClass
    {
    public:
         MyClass();
         static MyClass *instance;
         static void myMethod(int a, int b);
         int name;
    };

    MyClass  *MyClass::instance = 0;

    MyClass::MyClass(){
    if (instance)
        exit(-1);
    instance = this;
    }

void MyClass::myMethod(int a, int b){
        if(instance->name == a) qDebug() << "hello";
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass cls;
    cls.myMethod(1,2);
}
```

I'm trying to debug `myMethod` by stepping into it with the debugger. When i enter the method, only the `a  1`  and `b  2` are visible in the watch and there is no reference to `this` or `instance`.

**Update**
The answers stated that static methods are not bound to the object which is why there is no `this` available.

In this implementation, the static method accesses the `instance` and that's what I'd like to have available in the debugger once i step into `myMethod`.

How would I make that available/visible?

Comment: Your edit makes no sense, as I do see `intance` in debuger. Seeing that, it is easy to see `instance->name`

Comment: @BЈовић I've missed the essence in the code sample, i apologize. Here is a reproducible update in which the `instance` isn't accessible.

Comment: *the static method accesses the instance and that's what I'd like to have available in the debugger once i step into myMethod* Set a watch on `MyClass::instance` ?

Comment: @ta.speot.is Great, completely forgot about that. Figured it would be automatically shown if it's available.

Comment: Visual Studio has an "Autos" window that'd probably do it automatically for you but I don't know what gdb is capable of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static methods are actually called without an object. The call

```
MyClass cls;
cls.myMethod(1,2)
```

is equivalent to

```
MyClass::myMethod(1, 1)
```

As a consequence `myMethod` is not receiving any `this` value.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that static methods don't act on any object and there is no `this`. Actually, it's quite unusual to call static function on an object. This would do the same and is the more usual way to call satic functions:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass cls;
    MyClass::myMethod(1,2); //look Ma, no object!
}
```

With this it becomes obvious that the cls object is not needed at all in your example code, so you could leave it out entirely. The same applies to the arguments to `main`, since you don't use them.

Answer (score 3):

Such behavior is to be expected, since a static method has no access to `this`, as it is not bound to an object.

Simple solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15847336/476681) :

> You cannot access a non static member inside a static method unless you explicitly make available the object instance inside the member function.(Pass object instance explicitly as argument or use a global instance which can be accessed inside the function)

That means to change the method into this :

```
static void myMethod(MyClass instance, int a, int b);
```

Comment: Updated the question. Since `myMethod` is successfully accessing the `instance` without having it as a parameter, i am wondering if it is possible to get it in the debugger without changing the code (adding `MyClass instance` as a parameter).